# Activity not starting

Tags: android

I can get the progress dialog to stop, but the TabbedView activity never starts, just goes to a black screen. Any ideas?

```
    class DownloadWebPageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    private final ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(MainScreen.this);
     @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            dialog.setMessage("Gathering data for\n"+selectedSportName+".\nPlease wait...");
            dialog.show();
        }


    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
        String response = "";
        updateMaps();
        return response;
    }



    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
      dialog.dismiss();
      startTabbedViewActivity();
    }
}


private void startTabbedViewActivity(){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, TabbedView.class);
    intent.putExtra(SPORT_NAME_EXTRA, selectedSportName);
    intent.putExtra(HEADLINES_FOR_SPORT_EXTRA,         existingSportHeadlines.get(selectedSportName));
    intent.putExtra(SCORES_FOR_SPORT_EXTRA, existingSportScores.get(selectedSportName));
    intent.putExtra(SCHEDULE_FOR_SPORT_EXTRA, existingSportSchedule.get(selectedSportName));
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

I have looked over the Manifest file, and I'm not seeing anything weird looking. Can't figure this one out.

Comment: The ProgressDialog stops spinning, and holds for a few seconds, and then the screen goes black.

Comment: you can use `AsyncTask` refer this [developer.android.com](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Comment: try using async task and also as u are in the same activity there is no need to startActivity .

Comment: means you are try to start activity again that you are in it.

Comment: Yeah Async Task is best option for this kind of work...

Comment: You called pd.dismiss(); inside your thread, supposed to be called in the UIThread. Very suspect.

Comment: all of this is happening inside the Activity that calls TabbedView Activity, so I do need to startActivity. Also when is the appropriate time to call pd.dismiss()?

Comment: shouldn't the pd be dismissed when the new tab/activity is brought to the foreground?

Answer (score 0):

Is the layout of the activity orientated correctly

```
 android:orientation="vertical"
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add @Override above 'onPostExecute' method so it is not executed at all.

Comment: A small note. Because of this, when the task finishes, your application only calls the 'onPostExecute' method from the AsyncTask class (and not the one from your subclass).

Comment: I added the @Override, but apparently it's not the correct one to override. I am getting "must override or implement a supertype method" am I using the correct onPostExecute method?